# How to create customizable fragment in android library?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, customization, android-library

I'm working on android fragments for the library to used in open-source projects and i'm experienced with android controls customizing.

What is the best approach to create easy customizable (theming) fragments **in a library**?

Currently i'm going to use `dimen` values for some sizes and `style` for the views and i expect the apps to override them if needed. I'm not sure about dimensions as i don't know exactly what should be customizable and i can't set just any margin, padding in layouts at it seems to be too much work.

Also icons should be able to be replaced by the app developer.

Any suggestions?